# Passing PHP variable between files and inserting the variable into a SQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a PHP file that is getting a value through the URL through  $_GET.
The code is 
    $thisID = $_GET['blog_id'];

Now in the same file, I am collecting entries from a user and passing it through an HTML form with post to a file that enters the data into a SQL table.
I also want to enter the blog_id into the database.

This is the code I am using:

```
<form action="comment.php" method="POST">
Your name: <input type="text" name="display_name" size="25"><br>
Your email: <input type="text" name="email" size="30"><br>
Your comment: <input type="text" name="comment" size="40"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="blog_id"
value="<?php echo $_POST['$thisID']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

This is how I am entering the values into the SQL table

```
 $command = "insert into $table_name
values('','".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['comment'])."',
'".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['blog_id'])."',        
'".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['display_name'])."',
'".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."',now()
);";
```

The code is executed, I don't get any errors but the variable (blog_id) is not entered, the field in the database is null. All other fields are entered correctly.
Is it even possible to hand over a PHP variable like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="<?php echo $thisID; ?>">
```

cause you have already stored get value in a variable `$thisID`

if you want to send get data then use

```
<input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['blog_id']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be the $command query. You're model and controller is very mixed up there. I would set the POST into a variable, then escape that variable, then feed that variable into the query. Also, you said you're using GET, but your $command query shows POST. I would rewrite the query so that the manipulation happens before you give the variables to the $command query, and report back with the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah yo said that u are using `$_GET` but, you wrote `$_POST['$thisID']`;

1. Makes sure the `$_POST['$thisID'];` is the right value. just echo and see what shows up.

   $_POST['$thisID'];
2. If the value is showing up, then u should test with string the input tag to send by the form
3. If the problem persist, you should check the name or id maybe they've been using by other input tag and it won't working if you have the same id or name.